# Azure DevOps Connect-AzAccount no certificate was found in the certificate store

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell

I am trying to connect through an Azure DevOps Pipeline to several tenants, this is required in order to retrieve information of all of them to a central store for analysis purposes. An Azure PowerShell task in order to achieve this, to avoid the use of passwords I would like to authenticate with the certificate thumbprint instead.
On my machine I can do it without issues as I have installed the certificates on my Personal certificate store, however on Azure DevOps I can not do the same, when I attempt the Connect-AzAccount, the following error is displayed

```
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -ApplicationId "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -CertificateThumbprint xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Connect-AzAccount : No certificate was found in the certificate store with thumbprint xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

I am also using Connect-AzureAd as need other cmdlets that use this connection instead and I get the same error. Do you know if there is a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No certificate was found in the certificate store with thumbprint

According to your description, it seems that you are using the Microsoft-hosted agents.

So the certificate hasn't been installed in the `Personal Store` by default.

To solve this issue, you could try the following steps:

1. Export the certificates on your local machine.
2. Upload the certificates to `Azure Devops -> Pipelines ->  Library ->Secure files`.

[image]

3. In Pipeline, you need to download the secure files and install the certificates  to `Personal Store`.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download secure file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'filename'

- script: 'CERTUTIL -addstore -user -f "My" "$(Agent.TempDirectory)\test.cer"'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
   xxxx
```

**Note**: The `DownloadSecureFile` task will download the cer file to the agent temp folder.